# authentication problem in aspnet core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I want to put something like [isAuthenticate] at the beginning of the controller page, like the [Authorize] attribute or I want it to login to the page when it returns the answer "is authenticated" true . is there any way like this?

```
 [Authorize]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
```

I want to put something like this

```
[isAuthenticated]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

Comment: Within this `[isAuthenticated]` filter what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this site and can create your custom attributes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes